# Different .xsd using xsd.exe and VisualStudio->Xml->CreateSchema

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, xsd, xsd.exe

I have foo.xml, I would like to generate foo.xsd as it is generated with VisualStudio->Xml->CreateSchema, tried xsd.exe but results are not the same. (`xsd.exe foo.xml`)

How to call same command as VisualStudio->Xml->CreateSchema from command line?

Maybe one small example will help, notce `type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"` When xml is more complexed differences become huge.

xml:

```
<foo>
  <x />
  <y />
</foo>
```

VS:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="foo">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="x" />
        <xs:element name="y" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

xsd.exe

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
  <xs:element name="foo">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="x" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
        <xs:element name="y" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element ref="foo" />
      </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: I've not experienced this before.  How are the XSD from `CreateSchema` and `xsd.exe` not the same?

Comment: @psubsee2003 If you have not experienced this before, I would guess that you have not tried this before, or you are using some other options for xsd.exe ;) I have noticed this in VS2005 long time ago, and I see it again in VS 2012. See update.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it could be that Visual Studio is using `XmlSchemaInference.InferSchema` internally instead of xsd.exe? More information on [XmlSchemaInference.InferSchema.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162770.aspx)